# Moving Files with certain Extension using a textbox Directory vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, move

So i am developing an Desktop cleaner which moves the items depending on the extension to an specific directory (the one that is being cleaned)

The user defines the names of the folder which the items will be placed.

But the code to move the files doesn't work properly.

```
Private Sub FlowButton1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FlowButton1.Click
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        Dim folderPathTextBox = options.TextBox1.Text
        Dim files() As String
        files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(options.FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.txt")

        For Each file As String In files
            System.IO.File.Copy(file, options.TextBox1.Text & options.TextBox8.Text & options.TextBox2.Text & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file))
        Next

    Else
    End If
```

- `options.TextBox1.Text` = Directory selected using Folder dialog E.G: "C:\directory"
- `options.TextBox8.Text` = slash to separate = "C:\directory\"
- `options.TextBox2.Text` = Folder name determined by user E.G Images = "C:\directory\images"

I also want the code to check if the folder exist if not create it .

Thanks any help is appreciated

Comment: Use a try-catch block around File.Copy to prevent unhandled exceptions. print the " option.Textbox1.text ..... " line and check if the path is correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas to help you organize/simplify your code:

1. Name your `TextBox`'es properly. If you cannot do it, declare meaningful local variables and use that in code. It would greatly improve readability.
2. Use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) to join `C:\directory` and `Images` together. Get rid of `TextBox8`.
3. <s>I think you can safely drop `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)` part as well, should be able to just use directory as a copy target.</s> `File.Copy` expects a file name as a second parameter. You would need to use `Path.Combine` overload that accepts 3 parameters, and combine base path + user specified folder + the file name.
4. When using [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx), make sure you don't have this file in target already. According to MSDN, `Overwriting a file of the same name is not allowed`.

Comment: Thank you very much ;) the only thing that wasn't really right was dropping "System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)" since i need the file name to move it

Comment: @user1086384: You are right, `File.Copy` needs two file names, and second parameter `cannot be a directory`. Sorry, I did not read MSDN well enough before posting. :) I am glad that you were able to resolve it!

Answer (score 0):

Another good way to iterate thru files in a folder is to use DirectoryInfo
Dim di as DirectoryInfo

di = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectoryInfo("path to directory")
For Each f as FileInfo In di.GetFiles("*.txt")
'you have all kinds of options on the FileInfo objects including Copy.
Next

DirectoryInfo also provides an Exists property to determine if your dir is actually there!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to move all images of sub folders to a new folder.
Here is what I came up with to work.

```
    Dim WantedExtention As String = ".Your Type"
    Dim sourcePath As String
    Dim destinationPath As String

    'Somewhere else in the code to set the path is by paste not folder selection.
    FolderInfo = New DirectoryInfo(txtSelectedPath.Text)
    SelectedFolder = txtSelectedPath.Text
    Try
        'Check if it exits (Why its not False, Not too sure, but this worked)
        If Directory.Exists(SelectedFolder + "Move Folder") = True Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(SelectedFolder + "Move Folder")
        End If
        destinationPath = Path.Combine(SelectedFolder + "Move Folder")

        For Each subdir In FolderInfo.GetDirectories()
            'Since I am making the sub folder in the Root Folder I had to Skip the folder
            If (subdir.Name = "Move Folder") Then
                Exit For
            End If
            sourcePath = Path.Combine(SelectedFolder, subdir.Name)

            Dim picList As String() = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*" + WantedExtention)

            For Each f As String In picList
                Dim fname As String = f.Substring(sourcePath.Length + 1)'Don't know why this is hear yet - but ya need it
                FileCopy(Path.Combine(sourcePath, fname), Path.Combine(destinationPath, fname))
            Next

        Next
        lblCompleted.Text = "COMPLETED"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```